# Join two or more DFs with same size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have two data frames as shown below:

[`dataframe 1`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UYQ4fkB7RuU-4Zp0TyFL4zVaSkLZ6EL35EhcrPFNreM/edit?usp=sharing)

[`dataframe 2`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18tMwoPp7AxOE4NmGQXj1Ur7K7h7hqaJJSLF0tgUMfkU/edit?usp=sharing)

And input parameters CSV:

[*parameters csv*](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i6p4fUdzFUjY3PNblXUZkr540lYWIjtVfHWQdA0BNcc/edit?usp=sharing)

From the two DFs, I can generate this graph:

[image]

Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df_1 = pd.read_csv("2DBM_50x50_Central_Aug21_Sim.cliped.csv")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("2DBM_50x50_Mauari_Aug21_Sim.cliped.csv")
df_all = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=0)

variables = ["AAG", "DENS", "SRG", "RCG", "Thick"]
var_range = range(1, 101)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
flattened_axes = fig.axes
flattened_axes[-1].set_visible(False)

for i, var in enumerate(variables):
    var_columns = [f"TB_acc_{var}[{j:05}]" for j in var_range]
    data = df_all.melt(id_vars=["Period"], value_vars=var_columns, value_name=var)
    ax = flattened_axes[i]
    sns.boxplot(x="Period", y=var, width=0.2, linewidth =3, data=data, ax=ax, showfliers=False, color = "skyblue")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, I needed to do it by integrating the code with *parameters csv*. So, I have:

[Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nI475au9SR2yPQfav8GgyEgHQlb2xZde/view)

This code generates separated graphs for each line of the *input CSV*, and each one has a *DF* input:

graph df_1:

[image]

graph df_2:

[image]

My task, therefore, is to make the code integrated with the *parameters CSV* able to join both *DFs* in a single *DF* and then plot it into a single graph.

---

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Please do not delete images that are essential to understanding a question. There is a limited opportunity to delete questions you no longer need, which can be done if the question has not attracted any upvoted answers. Since you have an upvoted answer, I believe you cannot delete, unless the answerer deletes their post. We generally discourage this, as it is a destruction of content.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to read your `parameters.csv` file and filter the rows that are `TRUE`. Then, select the `FilePath` column from its output to read and concatenate the respective dataframes.

```py
import pandas as pd

parameters = pd.read_csv('parameters.csv')
files_to_read = parameters[parameters['DoScenario']]['FilePath']
dfs_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files_to_read]
df_concat = pd.concat(dfs_list, ignore_index=True)
```